# In Corda, NullPointerException when calling DataVendingFlow

Tags: corda

In Corda 3.3, I have defined the following flow:

```
@InitiatingFlow
class CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlow(val signedTransaction: SignedTransaction, val parties: List<Party>): FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val sessions = parties.map { initiateFlow(it) }
        return subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(signedTransaction, sessions))
    }
}
```

When my node executes this flow, I receive the exception below. What is the cause?

> [WARN ] 16:03:05,481 [Node thread-1] (FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:111)
>   flow.[55214e22-74aa-4f1b-a94d-6353d5bbf35d].run - Terminated by
>   unexpected exception {} java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.suspend(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:514)
>   ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.sendInternal(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:370)
>   ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.initiateSession(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:434)
>   ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.sendAndReceive(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:198)
>   ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.sendAndReceive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:29)
>   ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.sendAndReceive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:40)
>   ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.core.flows.DataVendingFlow.sendPayloadAndReceiveDataRequest(SendTransactionFlow.kt:70)
>   ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.core.flows.DataVendingFlow.call(SendTransactionFlow.kt:48)
>   ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.core.flows.DataVendingFlow.call(SendTransactionFlow.kt:31)
>   ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.core.flows.CollectSignatureFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:142)
>   ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.core.flows.CollectSignatureFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:135)
>   ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.core.flows.CollectSignaturesFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:114)
>   ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.core.flows.CollectSignaturesFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:64)
>   ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at com.example.flow.ExampleFlowMatching$CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlow.call(ExampleFlowMatching.kt:280)
>   ~[classes/:?]
>       at com.example.flow.ExampleFlowMatching$CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlow.call(ExampleFlowMatching.kt:277)
>   ~[classes/:?]
>       at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at com.example.flow.ExampleFlowMatching$ExampleFlowMatchingInitiator.call(ExampleFlowMatching.kt:170)
>   ~[classes/:?]
>       at com.example.flow.ExampleFlowMatching$ExampleFlowMatchingInitiator.call(ExampleFlowMatching.kt:45)
>   ~[classes/:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96)
>   [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44)
>   [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
>       at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
>       at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100)
>   [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
>       at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91)
>   [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [?:1.8.0_191]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_191]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   [?:1.8.0_191]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   [?:1.8.0_191]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [?:1.8.0_191]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [?:1.8.0_191]
>       at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62)
>   [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?] [WARN ] 16:03:05,491 [Node thread-1]
>   (StateMachineManagerImpl.kt:79)
>   flow.[55214e22-74aa-4f1b-a94d-6353d5bbf35d].uncaughtException - Caught
>   exception from flow {} java.lang.IllegalStateException: Was expecting
>   to find transaction set on current strand:
>   Fiber@10000009:[55214e22-74aa-4f1b-a94d-6353d5bbf35d][task:
>   co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask@4ca7589a(Fiber@10000009),
>   target: null, scheduler:
>   net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManagerImpl$FiberScheduler@599eed84]
>       at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.DatabaseTransactionKt.getContextTransaction(DatabaseTransaction.kt:14)
>   ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.rollbackTransaction$node(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:151)
>   ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManagerImpl$initFiber$3.invoke(StateMachineManagerImpl.kt:460)
>   ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManagerImpl$initFiber$3.invoke(StateMachineManagerImpl.kt:63)
>   ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.processException(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:131)
>   ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:112)
>   ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44)
>   ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
>       at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
>       at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100)
>   [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
>       at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91)
>   [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [?:1.8.0_191]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_191]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   [?:1.8.0_191]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   [?:1.8.0_191]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [?:1.8.0_191]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [?:1.8.0_191]
>       at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62)
>   [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]

Answer (score 1):

As of Corda 3.3, the `call` method in a flow needs to be annotated with `@Suspendable` so it's execution can be checkpointed.

So you should rewrite your flow as follows:

```
@InitiatingFlow
class CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlow(val signedTransaction: SignedTransaction, val parties: List<Party>): FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val sessions = parties.map { initiateFlow(it) }
        return subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(signedTransaction, sessions))
    }
}
```